# Magento Admin page is not loading at all

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

My magento admin page is also not loading up but my website is loading up properly. There was a re-integration of my payment gateway been worked on at the back end. Not sure where something has gone wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide the magento version and what is the error that is getting displayed when you try to access the admin page or is it just showing a blank page, can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: Magento version is 1.9 as per my knowledge. And the error message on the the admin page is

Comment: @Monit Can you check the var/report/ folder of your Magento installation and check for the filename with that log record number, the file should contain the exact error message.

Comment: Can you check the var/report/ folder of your Magento installation and check for the filename with that log record number, the file should contain the exact error message.

Comment: I have found the error file that you have mentioned in var / report / folder ...but how do I get back my Admin panel page ? Please advise in detailed steps to rectify the error. Thanks again for your help and support.

Comment: The file you found inside the var/report  folder contains the the exact error.  Can you please post the contents of file?

Comment: Magento  admin page there has been an error processing your request.
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record no 1019872076137 If I click on the link it redirects to 404 error page.

Comment: I shall check the file error message and shall post in some time

Comment: When I click on the error ... It redirects to my website with the error message. Whoops, our bad.... The page you requested was not found , and we have a fine guess why.

Comment: Atish...any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Magento there has been an error processing your request.
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record no 1019872076137 
If I click on the link it redirects to 4040 error page.